# How do I know when a DNS NS type record is set correctly?

Tags: dns

I bought a domain `xyz.example` on `dymmer.com` and the registrar automatically created an NS DNS record to link `xyz.example` to their own name servers.

Now, I want the subdomain `abc.xyz.example` to lead to the name servers over at `vercel.com` where I host my site. I have added a new NS type record telling it to point `abc.xyz.example` to `ns1.vercel-dns.com` but over at Vercel, it is telling me that it is still pointing to the Dymmer name servers.

I suspect this is because `xyz.example` is still linked to the Dymmer servers which catches all subdomains as well and the NS rule for `abc.xyz.com` has not yet propagated but I can't be sure of that and I read that it can take up to 48 hours.

However, as an alternative, Vercel suggest to add a CNAME rule to point `abc.xyz.example` to `alias.zeit.co` and that works instantly (again, probably because anything `xyz.example` goes via the Dymmer name servers name servers and then it reads the CNAME rule). Removing the CNAME rule also instantly breaks the forwarding to Vercel.

So, my questions then are:

- Did I set up the NS type rules correctly and some time in the next 2 days it will suddenly start working?
- Is using the `CNAME` instead of properly using the Vercel name servers an OK way to do it? It doesn't seem to be a redirect to the browser when I trace the route so for SEO that seems fine.

Comment: This might help to ensure you have everything set up OK: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93897/can-i-use-different-nameservers-for-different-subdomains

Comment: The site provides a form to fill out instead of literal DNS entries but it looks to be correct. It still hasn't been applied down the DNS chain so I'll have to wait to see if I actually did do it right. That still leaves the CNAME question because that is quick, simple and instant. But in IT, quick and simple is often quick and dirty.

Comment: Do not use fake domains as example, this is bad obfuscation. I edited your post for that. Also there is no DNS propagation, you have nothing to wait if you query authoritative nameservers to troubleshoot. But since you removed the only useful information ( the real domain name) noone can answer your question appropriately. Also your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to delegate authority over `abc.xyz.com` to the name server `ns1.vercel-dns.com`, you did it correctly. That would mean that they can add/delete/modify **any record within that subdomain**, at any time, and that would be recognized by the outside world. At this point it is difficult to determine what went wrong unless you do it again and provide the real domain name so we can take a look.

By adding CNAME yourself (and without delegating subdomain), that change will also have the effect (for that hostname only of course) but any further changes/updates will again have to be made by you.

DNS settings have nothing to do with browser redirects, they only translate between the hostname and the ip address.

Comment: It is an interesting remark that using an NS record delegates it fully and gives them control. That's not really something I would want. Now, while DNS may not redirect a browser, it does have a path that is extended by the CNAME because it passes by the nameserver that manages `xyz.com`. Somehow, the NS records still have not taken any effect and I have now changed it to CNAME based on you comment but I do still wonder: if I kept the NS record and it worked, would it resolve the subdomain via the nameserver that resolves `xyz.com` or skip it and go straight to the vercel nameserver?

Comment: @MartijnVanLoocke "That's not really something I would want." The DNS works by delegation. It is its design. Trying to go around that may only lead to further problems.

Comment: @MartijnVanLoocke "Now, while DNS may not redirect a browser, it does have a path" No, there is no "path" in the DNS, this is an HTTP level notion.